# How to retain latest record and delete older one in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has order by desc values like this

```
aaa  12am
aaa  11am
bbb  12am
bbb  11am
```

I need to delete row 2 and row 4 and keep the latest one

Comment: Do you have some ordering column? Like incrementing ID?

Comment: No only two columns, order by desc based on date

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timefield DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE rn > 1
```

`rn=1` identifies the latest record per slice. Delete operation performed on the `CTE` is propagated to the real table and deletes everything *but* the latest record.

**Edit:**

To just select lastest record per slide use:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name 
                             ORDER BY timefield DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: how do i do it if i don't want to change table but as query output

Comment: @user3831886, change `delete` to `select` :)

Comment: What is 'partition by name'

Comment: @user3831886 you can change it to : partition by COL1. basically, its the your column name that has 'aaa' and 'bbb' value inside